# Can I permanently hide the YouTube chat window?

Tags: youtube

YouTube started rolling out chats next to videos:

[image: "Top chat replay" box showing chat messages from various users]

This is often/always(?) open when I start playing a video.
It happens with live replays, recorded replays, and prerecorded videos (it is unclear to me when a video can have a chat).

Is there a setting to disable the chat, or have it start closed by default?

Comment: Please read Youtube Help Center -> [How to use YouTube Live chat](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en)

Answer (score 15):

You can with Ad Block Plus.

Add a filter

> youtube.com###chat

That will block the DIV that supports the chat.

Answer (score 5):

For normal youtube.com, there is currently no builtin or easy way to make the YouTube chat disable / hide / start hidden.

The "Disable Live chat" quote from YouTube Help in the previous answer is not relevant here, because it is help for people who upload the streams/videos, not for the people who play videos.

Updated 2023: This http://youtube.com/tv no longer works on desktop browser, just redirects to normal youtube. Per @andrew-t , thank you.

> An [interesting workaround that may work for some people](https://support.google.com/youtube/forum/AAAAiuErobUJXpC55JwIj8?hl=en) is
> browsing the http://youtube.com/tv version of the site made for TVs.
> It is a simpler version of the site that strips many features,
> including chat for now.

Answer (score 5):

Click "Hide Chat" (Live) or "Hide Chat Replay" (Live Replay) at the bottom of the chat window:

[image]

As of 2020-12-16 there is no way to do this via the Youtube settings. Unfortunately just in the interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Improve YouTube!](https://improvedtube.com/)** — an open-source browser extension that can tweak YouTube in various ways: such as hiding or collapsing various UI elements, like the “live chat” part of the UI ([Chrome version](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/improve-youtube-video-you/bnomihfieiccainjcjblhegjgglakjdd/) / [Firefox version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-addon/)).

After installing Improve YouTube!, hide or collapse the "live chat" in the right sidebar by clicking the extension's button → Appearance → Sidebar → Live chat → "Hidden" or "Collapsed." Settings screenshot:

[image: screenshot of settings described above]

Note: I have **no affiliation** with the "Improve YouTube!" browser extension in any way whatsoever. I'm just a regular user who wanted to share a solution to the OP's question about "hiding the YouTube chat window." I found this extension to be a relevant and helpful solution, since I also prefer to watch YouTube videos without the chat window.

Answer (score 0):

Also... the old trick. Right Click on Chrome > Inspect ... select the code and delete.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Clik to Remove Element extension on the Chrome browser. It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

From [YouTube Help](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en):

> **Disable Live chat**
>
> > You can disable Live chat at any time, even after the event has started.
> >
> > - **Stream Now:** Select the gear icon and uncheck the Enable live chat box.
> > - **Events:** Go ;to **Edit > Basic Info > Advanced Settings**. Under "Chat," uncheck the **Enable live chat** box.

Comment: Aren't those options for live stream _hosted_ by oneself instead of those _watched_?