# How can I go back from YouTube TV to 'normal' Youtube

Tags: youtube

I followed the advice in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/122922/55949) and entered `https://youtube.com/tv` in my FireFox browser. A login screen appeared which I could skip and indeed, all videos appeared in a large full screen format.

But now everytime I go to Youtube I get that format!
(Even in some *continue where you left off* state).

How do I get my previous 'browser' Youtube interface back?

Comment: You can give them feedback here: https://www.youtube.com/tv_feedback. I can't reproduce your issue with Chrome. When I type in youtube.com, it just goes back to the normal browser view. I did link my phone and login though. Perhaps if you clear your cookies or try a private browser session.

Answer (score 1):

Signing out from Youtube (Google) and then signing back in seemed to do the trick.